# Why is this quicksort code in C not sorting?

Tags: c

My logic seems correct. But I don't know what is wrong with this code. Please help to find the error. This code is almost showing the same entered array. What am I doing wrong?

```
#include <stdio.h>

void swap(int *p, int *q) {
    int temp;
    temp = *p;
    *p = *q;
    *q = temp;
}

int quicksort(int a[10], int left, int right) {
    static pivot;
    if (pivot == left) {
        if (a[pivot] > a[right]) {
            swap(&a[pivot], &a[right]);
            pivot = right;
        } else
            right--;
    } else {
        if (a[pivot] < a[left]) {
            swap(&a[pivot], &a[left]);
            pivot = left;
        } else
            left++;
    }
    if (pivot == right == left) {
        left = 0;
        pivot = 0;
        right--;
    }
    if (right != 0)
        quicksort(a, left, right);
    else
        return;
}

main() {
    int a[10], i, n;
    scanf("%d", &n);
    for (i = 0; i < n; i++)
        scanf("%d", &a[i]);
    quicksort(a, 0, n - 1);
    for (i = 0; i < n; i++)
        printf("%d", a[i]);
 }
```

Comment: What is the expected input and output? What is the real output? What is the error? A runtime error, compile error? Without you posting these details, it is difficult to answer your question.

Comment: "My Logic is correct." You mean you didn't write `quicksort()`, did you? "what am i doing wrong?" Using wrong code. You should use `qsort()` from the standard library for sorting. No reinvention of wheel except for learning!

Comment: ' what am i doing wrong' well, one thing is that you have not included the details of what you found out during your own debugging efforts.  That, and what @AshishAhujaツ has already listed. SO is not a debugging, test and verification house.

Comment: Switch your warnings on and you'll find that `pivot == right == left` is probably not what you want.

Comment: there a number of things wrong in it...which can be seen just from just seeing your code from a distance...for example the `pivot` variable is not given a value , like what are gonna compare with? garbage values...also i agree to @MartinJames and @AshishAhuja on this thing...

Comment: @ShreyanMehta: The `pivot` is a static variable, which will be initialised to zero. (The practice of keeping a state over recursive calls wit the static variable is rather doubtful, though. In this case that code can be turned into a loop, which means that the array is passed just once. Which also means that the array can't be sorted properly.)

Comment: @MOehm in some compilers it wont be initailized to zero...

Comment: @ShreyanMehta: It is a `static` variable. Static variables without explit initialiser will be initialised to zero. Uninitialised automatic variables have indeterminate valuies, aka garbage.

Comment: @MOehm you are right...it was my bad...just checked in compiler...it does initialize with zero...i had an image that it wont...

Comment: Guys there is no compilation error or something , the problem is with the output. Like If I enter 521643 it will give the output 123645

Comment: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=3OLTJlwyIqQ...... I saw this video and implemented as it is . Now tell me where am i wrong. Once again i would say there is no compilation error

Comment: Shreyan Mehta go and learn some c first . Static has the property to get initialized by 0 no matter what compiler it is.. If your compiler doesn't do it change your compiler its fraud..

Comment: Anyone Please see the comments above and respond as if What am i doin wrong

Answer (score 0):

Above code is not well formed. Quicksort is **divide and conquer** algorithm.

**The steps for quicksort is:**
1. Pick an element, called a pivot, from the array.

2.Partitioning: reorder the array so that all elements with values less than the pivot come before the pivot, while all elements with values greater than the pivot come after it (equal values can go either way). After this partitioning, the pivot is in its final position. This is called the partition operation.

3.Recursively apply the above steps to the sub-array of elements with smaller values and separately to the sub-array of elements with greater values.

Just for clarity in following case
n=5
5 4 3 2 1
The above code iterates only once and swap 5 with 1 and gives outcome as
1 4 3 2 5

For correct steps refer below code

```
#include<stdio.h>
void quicksort(int [10],int,int);

int main(){
 int x[20],size,i;

 printf("Enter size of the array: ");
 scanf("%d",&size);

 printf("Enter %d elements: ",size);
 for(i=0;i<size;i++)
 scanf("%d",&x[i]);

 quicksort(x,0,size-1);

 printf("Sorted elements: ");
 for(i=0;i<size;i++)
 printf(" %d",x[i]);

 return 0;
}

void quicksort(int x[10],int first,int last){
 int pivot,j,temp,i;

  if(first<last){
     pivot=first;
     i=first;
     j=last;

     while(i<j){
         while(x[i]<=x[pivot]&&i<last)
             i++;
         while(x[j]>x[pivot])
             j--;
         if(i<j){
             temp=x[i];
              x[i]=x[j];
              x[j]=temp;
         }
     }

     temp=x[pivot];
     x[pivot]=x[j];
     x[j]=temp;
     quicksort(x,first,j-1);
     quicksort(x,j+1,last);

  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for helping me buddy, I know to do this if i see the solution. But I wanted to practise by my own. Anyways thanks for helping.